# Pull data by searching unique ID

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I just managed to create my form and populate excel.
I would like to know if there is a way to create a new button that would pull info if it finds the unique ID.

For example:

```
Unique ID   Name     Place
1         John Doe   X
2         Jane Doe   Y
3         Tim Doe    Z
```

So for example, in the form, next to "Add" (which gets data in worksheet) I would like to have "Search for:" over here I would type the Unique ID and have all the other cells populated with info.

I am sorry if I should have provided more info. I am new to VBA. If needed, I can copy+paste the code.

If I add info and hit "Add this part" it auto-completes in excel on rows (A1: Unique ID; B1: Name; C1: Place).

I want to add another button like "Search" with this action: Click > Asks for Unique ID > It searches for the data typed > If it finds something populate textboxes with info(the row where SR is on A:A)

[image]

Comment: It's always a good idea to show your code, ideally a concise sample that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: you should not put the tag in the title (if they're not part of the question)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tags; it's my first post here. It seems I didn't read the rules very good :)

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way. As mentioned above, try to include a short bit of code that illustrates what you're attempting, and where it's not working. People (me) tend to get bored or confused reading long sections of code and move on to something else.

Comment: Thank you :) unfortunately I cannot upload images

Comment: @user2102571 provide a link to your image - someone with enough rep will add!

Comment: Hi Maks, here is the link: http://s7.postimage.org/j7po7nhiz/Capture.png

Thank you

Comment: so in this case..I would like to type the SR > hit a button > populate the other textbox with existing data

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are proficient enough to create a button and write the initial sub? Also I am assuming you've got only 1 column with the unique id, say column A.

```
Sub Find_Id()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String 
    strSearch = inputbox("Enter a Unique Id", "User Input")
    If strSearch =  vbNullString then exit sub

    Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole) 
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        'set text box values using rng1.offset(0, column offset).value
        TbxAddStep.value = rng1.offset(0, 1).value
    Else 
        'clear texboxes
    End if

End Sub
```

If you need more info I can provide, but this will find the cell and give you space to change your textbox values.